# How to partition a list to make each subset's size equal and mean as close as possible

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm

Suppose we have 3 lists each with 18 numbers like this:

```
list1 = {7.49, 7.56, 7.98, 8.09, 8.16, 8.21,
         8.73, 8.64, 8.68, 8.46, 8.57, 8.29, 9.38, 9.43, 8.95, 9.04, 8.9, 9.07};
list2 = {21.08, 21.18, 21.35, 21.79, 21.92, 22.15, 22.38, 22.48, 22.48, 22.51, 22.64, 22.68, 22.75, 22.8, 23.01, 23.28, 23.5, 23.54};
list3 = {36.33, 37.1, 37.19, 37.31, 37.34, 37.61, 37.88, 38.32, 38.42, 38.9, 39.06, 39.12, 39.14, 39.31, 39.39, 39.41, 39.41, 39.43};
```

I need to partition it into six subsets:

1. Each one with 3 numbers
2. The mean of each one is as close as possible to the others.

For an example:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Partition into 3 subsets: 
 1. Each one with equal size, it sould be `Length[list]/3=2`
 2. The mean of each subset is as close as possible to the others,it should be `{{1,6},{2,5},{3,4}}` where each subset's mean is `3.5`.

My objective is:

`Minimize` the `MeanVariance` of all the subsets.

Comment: Welcome to MMA.SE ! It would be interesting to provide a minimum working example, to actually show that you've searched and/or tried anything before asking the community. Moreover, its not clear to me what exactly do you mean with "the means of each onde are as close as possible."

Comment: You arrange the items in such a way that they all have a mean, say $x_{i}$ such that $x_{i}-\varepsilon \leq x_{i}\leq x_{i}+\varepsilon$ is satisfied and $\varepsilon$ is the absolute minimum you can determine given the initial list.

Comment: In other words you are looking at a k-means clustering variant. Or I think so :D

Comment: In the second condition, do you intend that the mean of every subset is as close as possible to the mean of every other subset, or do you intend that the mean of the three elements in the set are as close as possible to each other? Maybe you could show us for these 18 numbers the output you desire.

Comment: Yes, the mean of every subset should be as close as possible, as a whole, to the mean of every other subset.

Comment: Any idea how big list of numbers you actually want to partition. Or its just 18.

Comment: For the small example brute force would be : `aux = {#, Variance[Mean[Transpose[#]]]} & /@ (Partition[#, 2, 2] & /@ 
    Permutations[lst, {6}])` and `SortBy[aux, #[[2]] &][[1]]`. As hinted by @PlatoManiac, you need a better way for large lists.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Why don't you add this as an answer ?

Comment: @NikolaDimitrov Hope to come up with a worthy one.

Comment: I tried to use the NMinimize function,it took a while to solve,and only found a suboptimal solution.

Comment: Not at all a general or optimal solution, but **for your specific dataset** this seems to work nicely: `Transpose[FindClusters[list, 3]]` For other data it can produce ragged uneven subdivision, so there should be an even-out-and-sort steps included.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is very similar to the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is NP-hard...

Comment: Might be worth asking this on the Mathematics se

Comment: For list1, Vitaliy Kaurov's solution with FindClusters works well.I update two additional lists, and hope to seek a general and feasible solution to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 5):

A simple **approximate** version would work like this:

- Sort data
- Split on 3 sublists by 6 elements
- Reverse order of sublist with Max Variance
- Transpose to get 6 sublists by 3 elements

Here is the code:

```
subd[data_] := Transpose[MapAt[Reverse, Sort[Partition[Sort[data], 6], 
                   Variance[#1] < Variance[#2] &], -1]]
```

here is how it works

```
subd[list2]
```

> ```
> {{22.38, 22.75, 22.15}, {22.48, 22.8, 21.92}, {22.48, 23.01, 21.79}, 
> {22.51, 23.28, 21.35}, {22.64, 23.5, 21.18}, {22.68, 23.54, 21.08}}
> ```

and here are variances of mean values of sublists, which are pretty small:

```
Variance[Mean /@ subd[#]] & /@ {list1, list2, list3}
```

> ```
> {0.00137222, 0.000527407, 0.0127885}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is to split a list of `m*n` numbers into `m` subsets of size `n` whose means are as equal as possible. Here is an iterative solution. First, partition the sorted list into `n` sublists of size `m`, then reverse the even-numbered sublists, and transpose the array to get `m` sublists of size `n`. This will give a reasonably good initial approximation.

Then iterate over pairs of subsets. For each pair, find the split of the `2n` values that will make their means as equal as possible. Continue until the current split is best for `m(m-1)/2` pairs in a row. This will not necessarily find the absolute best subsets, but it will find a very good set. Restarting the iterations from the initial approximation many times, but with the order of the numbers in each subset randomized each time, is a convenient way to increase the chance of finding the absolute best set. (There is no way to guarantee that a set is best, short of checking all possible sets.)

To facilitate repeated randomized starts, I have rewritten my earlier code as a function. The last argument is the number of repetitions. It may be omitted, in which case only one start is used. The returned list is {subsets, subset means, standard deviation of subset means}.

EDIT - This revision addresses again the problem (noted by incognito007) that the results are susceptible to floating-point roundoff error. One possible effect is that the `While` can loop forever; this actually happened when the previous code was used to partition `list2` with `m = 3`, `n = 6`. The new code handles that case, but I can't guarantee that such looping can never occur when the data are `Real`. On the other hand, if all the data are exact then the arithmetic will be exact and the problem can not occur. One solution, exemplified below, is to scale and round the data, then undo the scaling at the end. Besides being safe, this will usually be faster, too.

```
funk[data_List?(VectorQ[#,NumericQ]&), m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive,
     r:(_Integer?Positive):1] /; Length@data == m*n :=
Module[{b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,L, v = Infinity, w},
d = Transpose@MapAt[Reverse,Partition[Sort@data,m],List/@Range[2,n,2]];
c = Prepend[#,1]&/@Permutations@Join[ConstantArray[1,{n-1}],ConstantArray[-1,{n}]];
i = Flatten[Position[#, 1]]&/@c;
j = Flatten[Position[#,-1]]&/@c;
If[And@@ExactNumberQ/@data, w := c.f,
  w := Total[f*c,Method->"CompensatedSummation"]; d = N@d; c = N@Transpose@c];
c = Developer`ToPackedArray@c;
Do[g = h = 1; L = 0; e = RandomSample/@d;
  While[L < m(m-1)/2,
    If[++h > m, If[++g >= m, g = 1]; h = g+1];
    f = Developer`ToPackedArray@Flatten@e[[{g,h}]];
    k = Ordering[Abs@w,1][[1]];
    If[k > 1, e[[g]] = f[[i[[k]]]]; e[[h]] = f[[j[[k]]]]; L = 0]; L++];
  k = Variance@Total[e,{2}];
  If[k < v, v = k; b = e], {r}];
{b, Mean/@b, Sqrt@v/n}]

list1 = {7.49, 7.56, 7.98, 8.09, 8.16, 8.21, 8.73, 8.64, 8.68,
         8.46, 8.57, 8.29, 9.38, 9.43, 8.95, 9.04, 8.9, 9.07};
list2 = {21.08, 21.18, 21.35, 21.79, 21.92, 22.15, 22.38, 22.48, 22.48,
         22.51, 22.64, 22.68, 22.75, 22.8, 23.01, 23.28, 23.5, 23.54};
list3 = {36.33, 37.1, 37.19, 37.31, 37.34, 37.61, 37.88, 38.32, 38.42,
         38.9, 39.06, 39.12, 39.14, 39.31, 39.39, 39.41, 39.41, 39.43};
```

First some results with `m = 6`, `n = 3`, the parameters in the original request.

```
Timing@funk[list1,6,3,1000]

{3.97, {{{8.9, 8.57, 8.16}, {8.64, 8.68, 8.29}, {8.73, 7.49, 9.38},
         {7.56, 8.95, 9.07}, {9.43, 8.21, 7.98}, {8.09, 8.46, 9.04}},
        {8.54333, 8.53667, 8.53333, 8.52667, 8.54, 8.53}, 0.0062361}}

Timing[.01*funk[Round[100*list1],6,3,1000]]

{3.22, {{{8.9, 8.57, 8.16}, {8.64, 8.68, 8.29}, {8.73, 7.49, 9.38},
         {7.56, 8.95, 9.07}, {9.43, 8.21, 7.98}, {8.09, 8.46, 9.04}},
        {8.54333, 8.53667, 8.53333, 8.52667, 8.54, 8.53}, 0.0062361}}

Timing@funk[list2,6,3,1000]

{4.79, {{{22.75, 23.28, 21.18}, {21.08, 22.68, 23.5}, {21.92, 22.51, 22.8},
         {23.54, 22.38, 21.35}, {22.64, 22.48, 22.15}, {23.01, 21.79, 22.48}},
        {22.4033, 22.42, 22.41, 22.4233, 22.4233, 22.4267}, 0.0091084}}

Timing[.01*funk[Round[100*list2],6,3,1000]]

{3.61, {{{22.75, 23.28, 21.18}, {21.08, 22.68, 23.5}, {21.92, 22.51, 22.8},
         {23.54, 22.38, 21.35}, {22.64, 22.48, 22.15}, {23.01, 21.79, 22.48}},
        {22.4033, 22.42, 22.41, 22.4233, 22.4233, 22.4267}, 0.0091084}}

Timing@funk[list3,6,3,1000]

{1.83, {{{36.33, 39.31, 39.41}, {39.12, 37.1, 39.06}, {39.14, 37.19, 38.9},
         {39.39, 38.42, 37.31}, {38.32, 37.34, 39.41}, {39.43, 37.61, 37.88}},
        {38.35, 38.4267, 38.41, 38.3733, 38.3567, 38.3067}, 0.0433803}}

Timing[.01*funk[Round[100*list3],6,3,1000]]

{1.49, {{{39.12, 39.06, 37.1}, {37.19, 39.14, 38.9}, {36.33, 39.31, 39.41},
         {39.39, 38.42, 37.31}, {38.32, 37.34, 39.41}, {39.43, 37.61, 37.88}},
        {38.4267, 38.41, 38.35, 38.3733, 38.3567, 38.3067}, 0.0433803}}
```

Now the other way around: `m = 3`, `n = 6`.

```
Timing@funk[list1,3,6,1000]

{9.85, {{{7.49, 9.04, 8.09, 9.38, 8.64, 8.57},
         {8.68, 8.46, 8.29, 8.73, 7.98, 9.07},
         {9.43, 8.21, 8.95, 8.16, 8.9, 7.56}},
        {8.535, 8.535, 8.535}, 0.}}

Timing[.01*funk[Round[100*list1],3,6,1000]]

{2.45, {{{8.21, 8.29, 8.73, 9.43, 7.98, 8.57},
         {8.9, 8.09, 8.95, 7.56, 9.07, 8.64},
         {9.04, 8.68, 7.49, 8.16, 9.38, 8.46}},
        {8.535, 8.535, 8.535}, 0}}

Timing@funk[list2,3,6,1000] (* this used to hang *)

{8.02, {{{22.68, 23.54, 21.35, 21.18, 23.28, 22.48},
         {21.92, 22.48, 22.51, 21.08, 23.5, 23.01},
         {22.38, 22.75, 21.79, 22.15, 22.64, 22.8}},
        {22.4183,22.4167, 22.4183}, 0.00096225}}

Timing[.01*funk[Round[100*list2],3,6,1000]]

{2.03, {{{22.15, 22.51, 23.54, 22.48, 21.35, 22.48},
         {22.38, 22.64, 21.79, 23.01, 21.18, 23.5},
         {22.75, 21.92, 22.68, 21.08, 22.8, 23.28}},
        {22.4183,22.4167, 22.4183}, 0.00096225}}

Timing@funk[list3,3,6,1000]

{9.31, {{{39.43, 37.88, 39.14, 36.33, 38.32, 39.12},
         {37.34, 39.06, 39.31, 37.19, 38.9, 38.42},
         {37.1, 37.31, 39.39, 39.41, 39.41, 37.61}},
        {38.37, 38.37, 38.3717}, 0.00096225}}

Timing[.01*funk[Round[100*list3],3,6,1000]]

{2.52, {{{39.14, 37.88, 39.12, 36.33, 38.32, 39.43},
         {39.41, 39.31, 37.61, 37.19, 37.31, 39.39},
         {37.1, 37.34, 38.9, 38.42, 39.06, 39.41}},
        {38.37, 38.37, 38.3717}, 0.00096225}}
```

Comment: Copying and running your code, I got the following result:{{7.49, 9.43, 8.68}, {8.9, 8.57, 8.16}, {7.56, 8.95, 9.07}, {9.38, 
  7.98, 8.29}, {8.64, 8.21, 8.73}, {9.04, 8.09, 8.46}};{8.53333, 8.54333, 8.52667, 8.55, 8.52667, 8.53};0.00960324. Why differs from your result?

Comment: @incognito007 It may be a version problem. The posted results are from 5.2, but 6 gives your results, and 5.2 with the data multiplied by 100 and then rounded also gives your results. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the optimal solution but may be satisfactory to your needs for these particular lists. Essentially, sort the list, partition into three groups of six. Mix the upper tertile with the lower tertile and then permute the middle till smallest variance obtained.

```
fun2[u_] := Module[
  {p, res, perm, mn, var, min, pos},
  p = Partition[Sort[u], 6];
  perm = Permutations[p[[2]]];
  res = MapThread[
      Append[#1, #2] &, {Thread[{p[[3]], Reverse[p[[1]]]}], #}] & /@ 
    perm;
  mn = Map[Mean, res, {2}];
  var = Variance /@ mn;
  min = Min[var];
  pos = Position[var, min];
  Thread[{Extract[var, pos], Extract[res, pos]}]
  ]
```

The results (sometimes not unique are presented as minimum variance of means of subssets and partition with minimum variance.

`fun2[list1]` yields

```
{{0.00112333, 
{{8.9, 8.21, 8.46}, {8.95, 8.16, 8.57}, {9.04, 8.09, 
    8.29}, {9.07, 7.98, 8.64}, {9.38, 7.56, 8.68}, {9.43, 7.49, 
    8.73}}}, 
{0.00112333, {{8.9, 8.21, 8.57}, {8.95, 8.16, 
    8.46}, {9.04, 8.09, 8.29}, {9.07, 7.98, 8.64}, {9.38, 7.56, 
    8.68}, {9.43, 7.49, 8.73}}}}
```

`fun2[list2]` yields:

```
{{0.000238519, {{22.75, 22.15, 22.38}, {22.8, 21.92, 22.48}, {23.01, 
    21.79, 22.48}, {23.28, 21.35, 22.64}, {23.5, 21.18, 
    22.51}, {23.54, 21.08, 22.68}}}}
```

`fun2[list3]` yields:

```
{{0.014593, {{39.14, 37.61, 37.88}, {39.31, 37.34, 38.42}, {39.39, 
    37.31, 38.32}, {39.41, 37.19, 38.9}, {39.41, 37.1, 39.06}, {39.43,
     36.33, 39.12}}}}
```